# Cloud9 IO disabling keybindings or Cloud9 alternative

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, cloud9-ide

I have found Cloud9.io and I'm going to use it for teaching people to code in html, css, javascript and php, but there is one problem. We all are czechs and if we want to create `{`, we press `Right-Alt` + `B` and for `}`, we press `Right-Alt` + `N`. However, that's a problem in Cloud9.io, whenever we press `}`, it thinks that we want to create new file, because we press `Rigth-Alt` + `N`. So is there any way to disable these keybindings, or edit their JS so it won't use any keybindings?

Or if it's not possible, do you know any alternative for Cloud9.io, that I can use for teaching other people to code, so they can see my coding live, it has a chat and they can also edit their files which I can see.

Thank you.

Comment: Set your keyboards to the US layout like normal people. (And I say that as a Slovak. You don't need diacritics when coding anyway, the quicker you learn QWERTY the sooner you can move on with what you're doing instead of trying to use the wrong tool for the job.)

Comment: Have you contacted the c9 support? If it's not possible to change key-bindings your issue might make them reconsider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now configure this under Preferences > Keybindings. Try double-clicking, pressing backspace and enter to remove an existing keybinding.